# Changing csh expression to tcl

Tags: tcl, csh

I need to change the following piece of code from shell to tcl.

```
if (!$?OSTYPE && $?OSREV && $?HOST))then
```

I need to know how to combine all the and conditions and then negate the combined result in tcl.

Comment: You need to do some basic research yourself. I just answered another similar question. Try googling tcl and operating system information together.

Comment: It's not a question on OS. I have clearly mentioned that I need to know how to negate the result of 3 and conditions evaluated together

Answer (score 1):

In csh, `$?FOO` is a boolean value that says whether the environment variable `FOO` is set. In Tcl, you'd use [`[info exists ::env(FOO)]`](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/info.htm#M14) to mean the same thing (and other variables can be tested this way too, of course, provided you can name them). Everything else is much more [recognizably](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/if.htm) [similar](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TclCmd/expr.htm).